# Combination Matrix of 2 dictionaries with custom function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries of key value pairs. I need a combination matrix representation that retains key information while performing a custom calculation on the value pair.

Input:

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
y = {'a': 3, 'c': 4}
```

Custom function:

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a*b
```

Desired output:

```
  | a        | b        | 
a | sum(1,3) | sum(2,3) |
c | sum(1,4) | sum(2,4) |
```

Is there any elegant solution to do this? I'm struggling to produce the desired result.

Comment: Why the tag `pandas`? Is this suppose to be a DataFrame?

Comment: _a combination matrix representation that retains key information_, How? What are you going to do with that? Could it be a dictionary with (xi, yj) values as keys? A dictionary with column-keys nested in a dict with row-keys? If you need a particular data structure, we need to know which operation do you need to perform on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary that stores the return value of your function call (func(x[x_key], y[y_key]) at --> key: tuple = (x_key, y_key)

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
y = {'a': 3, 'c': 4}

def product(a, b):
    return a * b

d = dict()
for i in x:
    for j in y:
        d[(i, j)] = product(x[i], y[j])

print(d)
```

This produces:

```
{('a', 'a'): 3, ('a', 'c'): 4, ('b', 'a'): 6, ('b', 'c'): 8}
```

Answer (score 0):

[I'm assuming you want the output as a DataFrame as your question has pandas as a tag.]

```py
# import pandas as pd

x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
y = {'a': 3, 'c': 4}
custom_function = lambda v1,v2: f'{v1}*{v2} = {v1*v2}'

df = pd.DataFrame({col:{
    ind: custom_function(cv, rv) for ind, rv in y.items()
} for col, cv in x.items()})
```

will result in `df` returning

> ```py
> ╒════╤═════════╤═════════╕
> │    │ a       │ b       │
> ╞════╪═════════╪═════════╡
> │ a  │ 1*3 = 3 │ 2*3 = 6 │
> ├────┼─────────┼─────────┤
> │ c  │ 1*4 = 4 │ 2*4 = 8 │
> ╘════╧═════════╧═════════╛
> ```
>
> <sup>(Printed with `print(df.to_markdown(tablefmt='fancy_grid'))`)</sup>

---

The dictionary used to build the DataFrame

```py
{col:{ind: custom_function(cv, rv) for ind, rv in y.items()} for col, cv in x.items()}
```

looks like

> ```py
> {'a': {'a': '1*3 = 3', 'c': '1*4 = 4'}, 'b': {'a': '2*3 = 6', 'c': '2*4 = 8'}}
> ```